# can't disable thumbnail preview with dconf-editor, Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dconf, thumbnails, previews

I want to disable thumbnail previews for 'text/x-python', 'text/plain', 'application/python', so I can get the cute blue and yellow snakes back as my icon. But somehow it refuses to respond to dconf or gsetting. I'm sure I set the inputs right like this: gsetting list-recursively | grep "thumb" --> 
org.gnome.desktop.thumbnailers disable ['application/python', 'text/x-python', 'text/plain']

I can have my pdfs previewed while python-text preview disabled using Humanity theme, but I would like run on ubuntu-mono-dark theme, which still previews the file. I suspect it has something to do with ubuntu-mono's playlist-automatic-symbolic.svg or playlist-symbolic.svg icon files. But I just don't know how to get around with it. Thanks in advance.

Yen-Yung